# Is there a way to subscribe to a button's enabled state?

Tags: angular

I have a template driven Angular form, the form has a submit button that is modified by external factors and is only enabled when the factors are satisfied after the page and its data has loaded.

I want to be able to know exactly when the button has been enabled (and the page has loaded properly) so that I can log the duration between page init and the page loading fully.

I thought this property might have been something that is exposed by the valueChanges observable of the FormGroup object, however the valueChanges only contains information pertaining to the FormControls found within a FormGroup. There is no information regarding the submit button.

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Even if you had a different sort of button, enabled state is not exactly a "value" of the control. I don't think you can do this directly. Is there anything else about the code that runs those "external factors" that you might intercept?

Answer (score 0):

As i said in your another post (!) you can use two-way-binding like this :

```
<button [disabled]="isDisabled"></button>
```

In your ts file :

```
isDisabled: bool = false;
```

- It's not necessary to set a value for 'isDisabled' variable in your ts component but you can get it's state from this variable when a change is happened.

Comment: This really doesn't tell OP exactly when the button got enabled. It only tells if the button is enabled or not at any one point in time.

Comment: @JoãoMendes You can observe this variable easily !

Comment: If you mean observe as in "get the value of the variable", then yes, you can. If you mean observe as in "subscribe to a reactive observable that outputs a new value when the variable changes", I'd like to ask for example code. :)

Comment: @IliaAfzali I appreciate your answer but I don't think this would work in this situation. I already have the disabled property bound to the return value of a method. `<button [disabled]="!canStartSession()">Submit</button>`. Would your solution still work?

Comment: @JoãoMendes Do you have any insight into how I could figure out when exactly a button has been disabled? I'm still stuck on this

Comment: Off the top of my head, I do not. The only thing I can tell you is, if you have access to the implementation of canStartSession, make it return an observable instead of just a boolean. Then, you can subscribe to that observable and you'll know exactly when a new value arrives.